# : is not a valid identifier

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

A colon cannot be used in the ID of a .NET control.  I quote from the following website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx

"Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error."

Is there a reason why alphanumeric characters have to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to find [on MSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx)...

> Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.

As for why, I cannot give an answer, other than it makes sense to me as a developer that you never use anything other than alphanumerics and underscores for variable names.  There's no obvious reason why that should not extend to control IDs as well.